# Making Eclipse show the topmost exception in its console instead of the full stack trace

Tags: java, eclipse, exception

Is there a way to make Eclipse show up in its Console the "top" exception instead of just printing all the stack trace and leaving me always with the screen filled with basically useless stuff? Here's a picture:

[image]

There are basically 2 things I might want to know in 99% of the times when there's an exception: it's name+message plus in which method it ocorred. None of them is visible without having to scroll up.
This is how I feel the data should be shown:
[image]

Is there a way to change this Eclipse's behaviour?

Answer (score 3):

1. I know of no Eclipse feature that will do this.
2. I disagree that the IDE *should* do this.  There's no way for the IDE to *know* what information in the stacktrace is useful or useless.  Scrolling the console to the supposedly useful part of the stacktrace based on some heuristic *might* help you a little bit today, but tomorrow it might hinder you *a lot*.  And the problem / danger is likely to be worse if you start folding or editing the stacktrace displayed in the console window.

Use the scrollbar Luke!

---

If you really think this would be a good idea, implement it and submit a patch to the Eclipse developers.  Or create a plugin.  Or use a different IDE.

---

By the way, the screenshot you included in your comment does not show an IDE scrolling a console window.  Rather it is showing an exception that has actually been delivered to the IDE as-is.  Eclipse can do this too ... to some degree ... as illustrated by the JUnit test view, the Error view and so on.  But this doesn't work if the stack trace has been rendered as text and written to a console window.  (For a start, the text format of a stack trace is not actually specified.)

Comment: I just find the way Eclipse shows us the data completely useless. It wouldn't be hard for Eclipse to be smart enough to "parse" the info that's shown. In visual studio, for instance, you are shown what you need : http://s3.amazonaws.com/satisfaction-production/s3_images/92506/untitled_inline.PNG (that is, both the exception message and the place where the exception was thrown. and you can still look at the call stack view on the right bottom).

Comment: @"I disagree that the IDE should do this. There's no way for the idea to know what information in the stacktrace is useful or useless." Your application terminates with an exception and still shouldn't it be the IDE's job to show you up the right info? Notice how I don't say in any place to HIDE the stack trace. Just to put the scroll on the right info (the exception). I could scroll down if I needed..

Comment: I would, if I had the time and the know-how!

Comment: Even if you are unable to contribute, I would at least recommend opening an enhancement request. Perhaps some kind of stack trace folding can be implemented in the console view. I would drop the sarcasm, though, or you will not get very far with your request.

Comment: yes it doesn't show an IDE scrolling the console window. but it shows how an IDE implemented the feature of showing up exceptions in a nice way.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a way in Eclipse to do this.

But I think the IDE actually has nothing to do with this. It is the JVM that is printing that output to the console since your program isn't catching the exception. If you ran it from command line, you would see the same output.

I think the program should handle the exception and print the desired level of information to the console.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the IDE has nothing to do with this. And you might want to rephrase that opinion as sometimes the useful information is not always the last executed line, but somewhere deeper in the stack trace (ex: an invalid value is passed to a method, down to the nth level where the exception occurs.)

Eclipse can't change this behavior as this is a run-time behavior of the JVM; when the exception is not catch, `System.err` is used to output the stack trace. You can change this by replacing the [error output stream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setErr%28java.io.PrintStream%29).

The `PrintWriter` that you set could keep the original copy of `System.err` and simply discard anything you don't care (i.e. anything matching "`^\s*(java(x?)\.).*`", or something) But the work around is not worth the trouble.

The better solution would be to catch and handle your exceptions and output something useful instead. The Java API is pretty explicit when some method throws an exception. There should be no surprise there.

Or another solution would be to avoid exceptions at all and be glad that Java prints a much useful stack trace to begin with and help you debug your application. Many language actually don't do that (or just not as good). If and when you deploy an application to a client, you'll actually be glad that the user sends you the complete stack trace instead of just a one-liner where the exception occurred.

Comment: "Indeed, the IDE has nothing to do with this. And you might want to rephrase that opinion as sometimes the useful information is not always the last executed line, but somewhere deeper in the stack trace " That is the 1% of the time.

Comment: And I still think people are not getting what I am saying. I am not speaking about clearing the stack trace, I am speaking of by default, showing up the name of the exception plus the method where it was thrown in the first place! The whole text message shown in the console would be the same, the way it was shown is what would be different!

Comment: @devoured, then trap your exceptions and show only what you want to show instead of relying on the default behavior. This is as simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an eclipse plugin like grepclipse or GerpConsole to filter console's output with regular expresions.

Comment: The Eclipse-Plugin is called `GrepConsole`. As Michel saied it is able to filter out the stack via RegExp. Its available here: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/grep-console